# iOS App always shows black screen when syncing with iCloud and transfer it from one iPhone to another iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, icloud

I am trying to do following steps.

- ABC appstore app installed on iPhone A (iOS 15 or iOS 16 installed)
- Now backup with iCloud in iPhone A (ABC app is already considered switch on from backup)
- Next we have another iPhone B with iOS 16
- Next in iPhone B , Restore with iCloud backup by same apple id which is used in iPhone A.
- Wait until all apps synced properly in device B
- **Now tap on ABC App, app always display black or blank screen.**

I tried below steps to find root cause.

- Added Logs at various places in the application code starting from didfinishLaunch appdelegate. But no logs are displayed in console or even i tried with swiftybeaver cloud base logger. but it also didn't report any logs from ABC App in device B. When app is in device A then all logging system worked well.

Note:- This issue not reproducible when restore by single iPhone and also if we update the version of the app in same device.

Comment: Note:- This issue is only for ABC app with iCloud. other apps which was restore from iCloud worked well without no issues.